# Warnings in xml resources

Tags: android, android-resources, android-lint

Yesterday I installed ADT plug-in again as I was having problems (intermittent) with the version I already had. The thing is, I'm not getting warnings in all my xml resources. I am pretty darned sure I haven't seem them before. Some of these are annoying because I cannot do anything about it:

```
Nested weights are bad for performance
The resource R.attr.TextAppearance_Group_Small appears to be unused
Replace "..." with ellipsis character (…, &#8230;)?
```

Others that I've had to fix include:

```
This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable
[Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image
```

Is there any way to suppress these warnings? We have a zero tolerance policy which does not allow us to check-in code with warnings?

Comment: You can't replace `...` with `&#8230;`? You can't remove an unused resource? Could you explain that to me?

Comment: I cannot remove an unused resource because it's not unused. It is being referenced elsewhere in code not through xml. Nested weights are bad for performance, I know, but I need to use it unless someone can explain to me how I could evenly layout a LinearLayout having two children. I will not replace (...) with (&#8230;) because I don't want to get calls from my localization vendors asking me to explain what (&#8230;) is. Hope it make sense.

Comment: I'm also getting warnings for code that does not belong to me. I have the sources, but don't have the liberty to change it.

Comment: Just a note, you shouldn't have to use the HTML escape for the ellipsis character. The literal character "…" should suffice unless you're parsing HTML out of that token (which is generally a bad idea anyway). Of course that doesn't prevent the translators from replacing it with three periods, but at least it shuts Lint up :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are warnings of the new [lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) tool for android, which got introduced with the latest tools. You can change the priority of the messages in Eclipses preferences.

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking`

[image]

Note though that this only affects your local installation. Hiding these messages will not fix the underlying issue(s). I guess someone checking your code on a different machine with different preferences may get the warnings nontheless.

Comment: Thanks. I found this http://tools.android.com/tips/lint which suggests a mechanism to add warning we want to ignore into a lint.xml file. This file can then be checked in and others will not see the warning.