# Android XML Editor: Don't notice error/warning. Just Red Hightlight

Tags: android, xml-editor

I'm using Eclipse for programming on Eclipse. Few days ago, I have installed many features of `Enterprise Edition` of Eclipse. When I program on Android and use Android Layout Editor again, I meet many strange thing:

1) I cannot reiceive error/warning. For example, when you use: `android:text="stackoverflow"`, Eclipse will warnning: use should use String resource at Left panel (maybe `x` or `!`). But, I cannot see it now :(

@: hightlight as you see on StackOverFlow, but instead blue, it's red :D

2) Instead of warning/error, I will hightlight red at that line. for example: `android:text="stackoverflow"`. And it's very difficult to me to follow.

I think maybe some config change, but when go to Windows\preference\android\Editor: I still cannot see any categories can fix it.

Please help me.

thanks :)

Comment: Here first day of me on StackOverFlow. Hope my post'structure is no error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I'm assuming that you are no longer seeing warnings or error notifications in the XML editor. Check your settings at `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Lint Error Checking`. Some error messages might have been set to `Ignore`. Any warnings or errors you want to see, you should set to either `Error` or `Warning`.

Take a look at [Warnings in xml resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575834/warnings-in-xml-resources). This might point you in the right direction and give you visual cues.

Comment: Yes. any warnings or errors here always set to warning/error, but still cannot fix.

Comment: @: for example, you often receive warning/error at left panel by `x` or `!`. but I cannot see it now :(